# My application UI looks all distorted on android 4.0 and 4.1

Tags: android

When I test my application on android 2.2 it seems to work fine . However when I test it on 4.0 or 4.1 the UI looks something like this. The text boxes appear greyed out with no border. Any ideas why this is happening?

Content of value-v14:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme" />

</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: That's Holo theme, that you defined on your `values-v14` folder.

Comment: I edited my question to show the content of values-v14

Comment: "Theme" is the legacy, pre-Holo theme. "Theme.Holo" is the Holo theme.

Comment: But I thought  it was the holo theme that was causing some issues. So I changed it to legacy. But it still shows the same behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: try to remove that folder if this is not the UI you want.

Comment: Did you define "android:targetSdkVersion" in AndroidManifest.xml?